# Regex that makes sure a match starts with a string

Tags: html, regex, preg-match

I am running a regex on some HTML and need to extract some image title tags.

The image title tags look like this:

```
title="Image Title Here"
```

And this works for the task:

```
(?<=title=").*?(?=")
```

However the problem is that it will grab unwanted title tags also. I noticed though in the HTML i run the regex on the images are inside h3 tags.

How can i update my regex to make sure it only gets matches from html starting with '

My current regex is:

```
(?<=<h3).*(?<=title=").*?(?=")
```

Comment: Regex and HTML are not good friends, use a parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `DOMDocument` with `XPath` should be less error prone:

```
$html = <<<DATA
<body>
<h1>Text 1<img title="Not this"></h1>
<h2>Text 2<img title="Not this"></h2>
<h3>Text 3<img title="This"></h3>
</body>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$imgs = $xpath->query('//h3/img[@title]');
$res = array();
foreach($imgs as $img) { 
   array_push($res, $img->getAttribute('title'));
}

print_r($res);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/8d7BTL)

The `'//h3/img[@title]'` xpath expression will find all `h3` tags that contain `img` children that contain `title` attributes, and `$img->getAttribute('title')` will get the value from these attributes.

Comment: Thanks, i am getting errors when i run the code though after i replaced the $html var with a url. Also i am just wondering, what if i did it on another tag that was actually a h1 or something that included a title tag, would it be '//h1[@title]' ?

Comment: To get the data from URL, you need something like `$html = file_get_contents('http://api.somesite.com');`. See [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) help.

Comment: That seems to work well, for some reason it works fine on the url but gets 30 items to the array then gives this warning: "Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : head in Entity, line: 132 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\test.php on line 15" do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Add the following line of code right after getting the URL contents: `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` - this will try to fix issues in the incoming HTML.

Comment: Many thanks, i think the page i run regex on must use slow loading as there is about 100+ images but it gets the first 30 items. I guess getting around that is another question though.

Comment: @zeddex To give you an idea how to load the other images: Load the page in a browser. Open the network tab of the developer tools. Scroll down (or whatever it takes to load more images) and make note of the HTTP requests. Replicate the same requests in your PHP code.